# CoreData is setValue(_:forKey:) necessary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

When updating an entity in CoreData, is it necessary to use `setValue(_:forKey:)`, or can you just set the value using the default setter?

`someEntity.setValue("Bob", forKey: "Name")`

vs.

`someEntity.name = "Bob"`

<s>The first method triggers KVC, the second doesn't (correct?).</s>

**The accepted answer confirms that the above is incorrect. @NSManaged enables KVC on Swift properties by default.**

So will the managed object context fail to recognize the changes? Are there any drawbacks to using the default setter? I can't find a definitive answer in any documentation. My tests show that it works just fine, but is there something that I don't know that'll come back to bite me in the future?

The closest answer I've found in any documentation is from the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html) under *Key-Value Coding with Swift*

> Swift objects that inherit from NSObject or one of its subclasses are key-value coding compliant for their properties by default. Whereas in Objective-C, a property’s accessors and instance variables must follow certain patterns, a standard property declaration in Swift automatically guarantees this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not correct, both methods trigger `KVC`.

- `setValue(:forKey)` is a generic method of `NSManagedObject`
- Dot notation is for `NSManagedObject` subclasses accessing `@NSManaged` properties. The attribute `@NSManaged` *enables* KVC.

Both methods do the same thing.

You can even use `setValue(:forKey)` in `NSManagedObject` subclasses but it's recommended (and more convenient and less error-prone) to use dot notation.

Comment: Thanks, I realized my assumption was incorrect after reading the KVC guide. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: Hey @vadian is there way to directly add ManageObject in to CoreData, Actually I'm trying to map api response to My ManageModel and store it directly in to Disk

Comment: What does *map api response to My ManageModel* mean?

Answer (score 3):

NSManagedObject has no entity properties: an entity type is not an object type, and an entity attribute is not a property. Instead, the entities are something of a myth (they are basically just a label), and the attributes must be accessed through KVC sent to an NSManagedObject.

If you didn't use automatic class generation, that would be *all* you could do.

In Objective-C, one solution to make things work a bit more nicely would be a category on NSManagedObject defining the entity properties as `@dynamic`, meaning that Core Data will synthesize a special setter and getter to use KVC *for* you.

Nowdays, things are even better: the compiler generates an NSManagedObject subclass for each entity type, whose properties are marked Swift `@NSManaged`, Objective-C `@dynamic`. So now you have actual classes and can use those properties instead. This is still nothing but a screen to generate the correct KVC calls for you.

The advantage of this notation, however, is obvious. If you use KVC directly, nothing prevents you from writing `forKey:"wooblededoo"` even though there is no `wooblededoo` attribute for this kind of entity (and indeed, in the old days this was a common mistake to make). But if you use classes and properties, the compiler confines you to using the actual properties for the actual classes based on the entity/attribute descriptions.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer! I'm accepting @vadian's answer since it's a more direct answer. Appreciate your input, though.

Comment: "NSManagedObject has no entity properties: an entity type is not an object type, and an entity attribute is not a property. Instead, the entities are something of a myth (they are basically just a label), and the attributes must be accessed through KVC sent to an NSManagedObject." - mind blown. thanks for the awesome answer @matt